# What does this error mean for me?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to get my array to display some elements from this array.

```
<?php
$data = array(
1000 => array( "id" => 1000, "number" => 2380, "name" => "CS2", 
                "instructor" => "Chen", "rating" => null ),
1001 => array( "id" => 1001, "number" => 2333, "name" => "Computer Organization and Assembly", 
                "instructor" => "Reilly", "rating" => null  ),
1002 => array( "id" => 1002, "number" => 3342, "name" => "Awesome", 
                "instructor" => "Tomai", "rating" => null  )
);

$ratings = array(
4 => "Excellent",
3 => "Good",
2 => "Drop",
1 => "F"
)
?>
```

I have this code set up to display the elements and for now it is just a barebone that really doesn't do much but at the very least I would like it to display what I have here but it keeps telling me that it can't display the array.

Error Details:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptiem\courses.php on line 29
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptiem\courses.php on line 30
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptiem\courses.php on line 31
```

Note: I purposely misspelled `phptiem` for my amusement.

and this is the code that I have so far that doesn't seem to really work with it. 
I also don't have short open tag on my server as it doesn't work so I am forced to use `<?php ... ?>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
 require_once( "data.php" );
 ?>
<html>
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
<h1>Course Listings</h1>
</div>
 <table class="table">
<?php
print_r($data);
foreach( $data as $key => $value  )
{
?>
<tr>
<td><a href="course.php"> <?php $value->number ?> </a></td>
<td><?php $value->name ?> </td>
<td><?php $value->instructor ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php
 };
?>
</table>
 </div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: where is the `$value` object initiated?  ... oh i see you mean `$value['number']` et al not `$value->number`

Comment: If you are going to quote errors and line numbers -- please tell us where those line numbers are instead of making us count.

Comment: *"What does this error mean for me?"* --- Shouldn't that be more like *"What does this error mean for you?"* ;-)

Comment: only *you* can stop forest fires

Comment: What'd you do with that Pick-a-nick basket Booboo?!

Comment: i drank the wine and smeared the honey on myself.

Comment: You're waiting on that Queen Bee to come along eh?

Comment: slowly as the years go by,  the time between ending work and starting drinking on Fridays gets earlier and earlier

Comment: @OP --- Sidenote: Missing semi-colon in `1 => "F"
)`

Comment: Time never stands still @Dagon it just gets better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using $value as an object. But it's really an array. You should print it out as $value['number'] or convert it to stdClass.

Mentioning printing. You are missing the echo commands in `<td><a href="course.php"> <?php $value->number ?> </a></td>` and other places alike.